# Android Face feature detection

Tags: android, face-detection

I am beginner in android and I want to start a face feature detection program 
I have already tried OpenCv but its too hard to handle. I want to know if there is any simple API that I can use

Comment: Google play services has a Face API if you want to  use that -- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.cy/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html

Comment: @Tasos thanks but it doest have any code :(

Comment: Go down  to Learn More :))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I really meant
it was the easiest and the best API for facial feature recognition and also face detection with happiness and open eyes probability
 you can see [here](http://arjunu.com/2015/08/face-detection-with-android-vision-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you examine the basic article about [Face Detection](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html). 
Then you can already see [examples of code github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision). Good luck in your endeavor.

In addition, I easily found this article in Google and sample code was at the end of this article. I would recommend you to read about [searching on the Internet](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000082.htm).

Comment: tnx I did search through it , its just good not to be offensive!

Comment: It was the second link. If the question is closed, you can click on the check about the answer.